# adding an if/else to change contents in the comparison table using ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml, if-statement

Thanks for stopping by. i need little help with this program/application that I'm trying to create. It is a web app which displays the various results from an XML using ajax. Following is the program which parses data from XML and shows it on the web page in the form of table. i have added 2 images in it, which is a cross and a green tick. Now,in the data fetched there are some attributes which shows the result OK or NOTOK. this can be seen on the page. So basically, i want those image instead of the text. Suppose, if the data is NOTOK, it should show a red cross and if it is OK, it should show green tick. I believe it can be achieved by if-else condition as the data can change and image should change accordingly. Can someone help me out on how should I apply if-else to change the display result.

```
 <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var CheckImage = "<img src='images/check.png' height='20' weidth='20'>";
    var CrossImage =  "<img src='images/cross.png' height='20' weidth='20'>";
    setInterval(abc, 100);
    function abc()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/XMLFile.xml",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "xml",
            cache: false,
            success: function (xml)
            {

            var tableContent = "<table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='5'>" +
            "<tr>" +
            "<th>SiteName</th>" +
            "<th>URLType</th>" +
            "<th>DNSStatus</th>" +
            "<th>TargetStatus</th>" +
            "<th>TTL</th>" +
            "<th>SSL</th>" +
            "<th>Force</th>" +
            "</tr>";
                $(xml).find('ProdURL').each(function ()
                {                       
                    tableContent += "<tr>" +
                        "<td>" + $(this).attr('ProdHost') + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + $(this).attr('URLType') + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + $(this).attr('DNSStatus') + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + $(this).attr('TargetStatus') + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + $(this).attr('TTL') + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + $(this).attr('SSL') + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + $(this).attr('Force') + "</td>" +
                        "</tr>";
                });


                $(xml).find('RootURL').each(function ()
                {
                    tableContent += "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + $(this).attr('RootHost') + "</td>" +   
                    "<td>" + $(this).attr('URLType') + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + $(this).attr('DNSStatus') + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + $(this).attr('TargetStatus') + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + $(this).attr('TTL') + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + $(this).attr('SSL') + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + $(this).attr('Force') + "</td>" +
                    "</tr>";

                });


                $(xml).find('WorkingURL').each(function ()
                {
                    tableContent += "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + $(this).attr('WorkingHost') + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + $(this).attr('URLType') + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + $(this).attr('DNSStatus') + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + $(this).attr('TargetStatus') + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + $(this).attr('TTL') + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + $(this).attr('SSL') + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + $(this).attr('Force') + "</td>" +
                    "</tr>";
                });


                $(xml).find('ModuleURL').each(function ()
                {
                    tableContent += "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + $(this).attr('ModuleHost') + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + $(this).attr('URLType') + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + $(this).attr('DNSStatus') + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + $(this).attr('TargetStatus') + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + $(this).attr('TTL') + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + $(this).attr('SSL') + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + $(this).attr('Force') + "</td>" +
                    "</tr>";
                });


                $(xml).find('VanityURL').each(function ()
                {
                    tableContent += "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + $(this).attr('VanityHost') + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + $(this).attr('URLType') + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + $(this).attr('DNSStatus') + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + $(this).attr('TargetStatus') + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + $(this).attr('TTL') + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + $(this).attr('SSL') + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + $(this).attr('Force') + "</td>" +
                    "</tr>";

                });

                tableContent += "</table>";
                $("#UpdatePanel").html(tableContent)
                getdata(tableContent);

            }

        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: <URLs><ProdURL ProdHost="www.wellington.ca" URLType="Prod" DNSStatus="OK" TargetStatus="NotOK" TTL="300" SSL="OK" Force="Yes" />
    <ProdURL ProdHost="www.facebook.ca" URLType="Prod" DNSStatus="OK" TargetStatus="NotOK" TTL="300" SSL="OK" Force="Yes" />

Comment: Please EDIT you question to include the text in your comment (formatted).

Comment: "there are some attributes which shows the result OK or NOTOK"...it would help a lot if we knew which one(s) you mean...

Comment: btw why are you using jQuery 1.7? It's very old and not supported any longer. The latest version in the 1.x branch (if you need IE8 support) is 1.12, or you can migrate to 2.x with no incompatibility, or use the latest 3.2.1 (which, in your code as shown, shouldn't be any problem). Always best to use a supported version of a key library.

Comment: @ADyson the attributes which I am regarding to is all of them, in my first comment above, there is a part of my XML file. Suppose if the data for DNSStatus is OK and it changes to NOTOK, it should should show RED CROSS instead of GREEN TICK..

Comment: @LakshitSharma If the info is important to the question in that way it should be in the question itself, not in the comments. I didn't notice it, especially because code in comments is not easy to read either. Use the "edit" button just underneath the little blue tags at the bottom of your question, and then you can add more info to it. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson i have added a new table in this called 'Time changed'.. is there any way if we can add a feature from which it displays the time stamp on which the data was changed in the Xml file??

Comment: Only if you can get that information from the server. Since it's a property of the file, rather than its content, then you might need a separate endpoint URL on your server which checks the date in the filesystem and then returns it - so you'd need a separate AJAX call for it. Or...you replace your current direct call to the file with a call to a script which returns the XML and the timestamp data in a single overall response object, possibly still in XML format to keep it simple.

Comment: @ADyson Okay so, for the current scenario, until the website goes live, can we add anything to test?

Comment: Have edited my comment above with more detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't said which attribute is the one which contains the OK and NOTOK values.

However, it doesn't matter much, the pattern of usage is still the same. For the sake of demonstration, let's assume it's the TargetStatus attribute which we're talking about. You can change this is in your code to suit the real situation.

All you need to do is read the value from the attribute, and depending on the result, incorporate the relevant image HTML (which you've handily placed into re-usable variables) into the string:

```
"<td>" + ($(this).attr('TargetStatus') == "OK" ? CheckImage : CrossImage) + "</td>"
```

The logic is very simple. You could do this more long-handed with a conventional `if` statement syntax, but this shortened [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) syntax is great for placing inside another statement like this.

Comment: I used this line above, but the image is displayed outside the table but not on the table instead of text...

Comment: So your first comment is a mistake, I hope? I honestly can't see how that's possible. Are you sure you did it right? You should end up with HTML looking something like `<td><img src='images/check.png' height='20' weidth='20'></td>`, no? Hopefully from your last comment you got it working now without a problem.

Comment: i have added a new table in this called 'Time changed'.. is there any way if we can add a feature from which it displays the time stamp on which the data was changed in the Xml file??